# Can ReactRootView be used in a cell in RecyclerView?

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, react-native, android-recyclerview

Recently I filed an issue to the native-react android project ([link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11546)) but still I have not received any answer. So I'm asking community here.

I'm using react-native in kind of unusual way, I'm trying to use `ReactRootView` in a cell in `RecyclerView`, but it does not seem to work properly when I upgraded react-native from *v0.24* to *v0.38*, rendering `ReactRootView` is broken (you can see more details in github issue).

To sum up, in `onLayout()` (in javascript code) method we call native (java/objective-c) code to update height for `ReactRootView` (without that, view itself can not do that, correct me if I’m wrong), in old version `onLayout()` method was called only once (and it was very fast 10-15 millisec), in *v0.38.0* (in android) it is called dozens of times within 3-4 sec.

Is `ReactRootView` can be used at all in a cell or is it bad idea and in future there will be more bugs because it is not supposed to be used in that way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: A year later.. Did you find out after all?

Comment: @SudoPlz Do not do this, it worked more or less fine for as in MVP, but when we went production it all fell apart. That was too much what we hoped react-native would do :(

Comment: I wonder why though. I'm building a synchronous view that will render ReactRootView's in a RecyclerView. I'm trying to resolve the biggest issue which is passing jsx views through the react native bridge.

So I think that's not all react-native can do. It can do more, because you can write the heavy stuff in pure native.

I've already done that on iOS https://github.com/SudoPlz/react-native-synchronous-list and now I'm porting it to Android as well.